# How can I duplicate different rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have single values in Ad Group column that I need to duplicate in the blank cells in the rows below. There should be 3 of each Ad Group name.

My first screenshot shows how it currently is:

[image]

My second screenshot shows how I need it:

[image]

There are 30k rows so I need a formula or dynamic way to achieve this.

Comment: You just need to use `F5` >>> `Special` >>> `Blanks`, with the area range selected, and then you will set the formula as equal to above cell (=A2 in A3).

Comment: @ElbertVillarreal With that Special > Blanks, I would still have to type in the name of the above cell for each blank, right?

Comment: In that case, yes... but check my answers and let my know if is good for you. And remember the last answer I give to you.

Comment: With the `VBA` you dont need to type anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my answer:

Using VBA:

```
Sub selectBlankCells()
    Dim r 'to store the number of the last row of data
    Dim rng As Range

    r = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row 'to find the last row
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(r, 2)) ' set the range of column B, of the data
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C" ' this is where you put the formula to
                                                               'set the data of above cell in every empty cell of
                                                               'column B
End Sub
```

Or you can use the Excel option:

Select the the data of column B, from the last row to the cell B1, then press `F5`, and this window appears.

[image]

Then press `Special...`

[image]

After that, select `Blanks` and `OK`

You will select only the blank cells, and then you can put the formula to link the above cell from the active cell.

This way using ([Ctrl]+[Enter] is needed to put the formula into all of the cells at once as Jeeped says):

[image]

You will get this:

[image]

Comment: Might be an idea to state that [Ctrl]+[Enter] is needed to put the formula into all of the cells at once in the manual method. You can also select the whole column; Excel will only find the blanks in the UsedRange.

Comment: You are Right @Jeeped, I missed that!